# Effect of transport encoding on XML encoding and character references

Tags: xml, http, utf-8, character-encoding, xml-serialization

This question involves the interplay between the [XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) and [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) recommendations.

I have a web service that accepts a well-formed XML 1.0 document, parses it, and re-serializes it back to the client. The service supports both Content-Type `text/xml` and `application/xml`.

Suppose the following document is submitted as `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii` with `Accept: text/plain` and `Accept-Charset: us-ascii`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<x>Inhoffenstra&#x00DF;e</x>
```

The above document is well-formed and satisfies the encoding requirement.

Once parsed, the XML DOM is UTF-8. Since the encoding of the document is also UTF-8, the document would be re-serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<x>Inhoffenstraße</x>
```

The above document is not compatible with the `Accept-Charset` header. However, there are at least three ways this request could be satisfied:

1. Serialize the DOM using encoding US-ASCII. This seems wrong and unnecessary because I am changing a fundamental property of the document, which may be misleading to the client (for instance, could this break something at the application layer, i.e., ESB/SOAP):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
   <x>Inhoffenstra&#x00DF;e</x>
   ```
2. Post-process the serialized UTF-8 in the service layer by replacing non-ASCII characters with their Unicode character reference. This feels like a hack because XML-specific character encoding is being performed on the entire document using a non-XML-aware string transformation:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <x>Inhoffenstra&#x00DF;e</x>
   ```
3. Reject the request in the service layer as `406 Not Acceptable`. This would assume that `encoding="UTF-8"` is in conflict with `Accept-Charset: us-ascii`. But, I don't think this is the case since the actual *content* of the request is composed entirely from ASCII characters.

What is the expected, standards-compliant behavior for the response? From my understanding of the referenced standards, any of the above might be acceptable.

The following answers to a different question provide some helpful information but do not specifically address the `text/xml` case:

[application/* Content-Type and charset attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273761/application-content-type-and-charset-attributes)

I'm linking the following question because I believe it stems from a related problem:

[Escaping Unicode string in XmlElement despite writing XML in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006146/escaping-unicode-string-in-xmlelement-despite-writing-xml-in-utf-8)

Comment: why do you submit as `text/plain` if you say that service accepts  `text/xml` and `application/xml` ?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

The standards-compliant response for the presented scenario is 415 Unsupported Media Type due to the conflict between the supported media type (text/xml, application/xml) and the media type of the payload (text/plain) in the request.

### Explanation

Content-Type is defined in [RFC7231 Section 3.1.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) as follows (emphasis mine):

> The "Content-Type" header field indicates the media type of the
> associated representation: either the representation enclosed in the
> message payload or the selected representation, as determined by the
> message semantics. The indicated media type defines both the data
> format and **how that data is intended to be processed** by a recipient,
> within the scope of the received message semantics, after any content
> codings indicated by Content-Encoding are decoded.

Because the media type of the payload is text/plain, we must process the submitted document as plain text ("how that data is intended to be processed").

So how do we process plain text?
Plain text is defined in [RFC2046 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1) as follows:

> Plain text does not provide for or allow
> formatting commands, font attribute specifications, processing
> instructions, interpretation directives, or content markup.  Plain
> text is seen simply as a linear sequence of characters, possibly
> interrupted by line breaks or page breaks.

XML defines content markup, processing instructions and other things.
Parsing a plain text document as XML, is a violation of the standards.

Lets take a look at your example:

```
<x>Inhoffenstra&#x00DF;e</x>
```

Converting `&#x00DF;` to `ß` is what you would do if the document is XML,
but if the document is plain text, it is a violation of RFC2046 and also [RFC5147](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5147#section-1.1) that confirms how plain text should processed.
As plain text, `&#x00DF;` means `&#x00DF;`, and nothing else.

In conclusion, none of the above possible responses you presented is standards-compliant.
The standards-compliant response of the presented scenario is 415 Unsupported Media Type.